# Command Strategy Class Not found in Spark 1.3

Tags: sql, scala, cassandra, apache-spark

I am using spark 1.3 and am able to create spark context . when i try to access a Cassandra DB using CassandraSQL context. I get the below error.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkStrategies$CommandStrategy
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext$$anon$1.(CassandraSQLContext.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext.(CassandraSQLContext.scala:64)
    at SparkSample$.main(SparkSample.scala:28)
    at SparkSample.main(SparkSample.scala)

I use the spark-cassandra connector from Datastax. Also that I am not able to see any documentation related to SQL Execution
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/java/index.html?org.apache.spark.sql.execution in spark 1.3 version.  Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you look at the Cassandra readme you will see that they do not support 1.3 yet. I'm sure they would accept PR's though :)

Now, to the crux of the matter; they are using package private pieces so they are prone to these types of breaking changes. If you look at [SparkStrategies in the 1.2 branch](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.2/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkStrategies.scala), you will see the `CommandStrategy` at the bottom. However, in [SparkStrategies 1.3](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.3/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkStrategies.scala), the last object has become `DDLStrategy`, which does not even look the same at a glance. So, they might have removed this altogether. Your best bet is to report this to the Cassandra connector project and wait for official support of 1.3

Comment: Yes, they dont seem to support. I got it working with spark 1.2.1. Thanks for your inputs